# canvas context gets reset when canvas width/height are changed

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

If I set `ctx.textBaseline = "top";`, but then resize the canvas, the `ctx.textBaseline` gets changed back to `"alphabetic"`. Is this expected behaviour? This problem had me stumped for a bit so I'm just curious. Happens in Chrome and Firefox, so my initial guess is that it's expected behaviour.

[Here's a demo of the problem](http://jsbin.com/yejagufosa/1/edit?html,output).

```
// textBaseline not working:
let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
ctx1.textBaseline = "top";
canvas1.width = 31;
canvas1.height = 31;
ctx1.fillText("hi", 10, 10);

// fixed:
let ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
canvas2.width = 31;
canvas2.height = 31;
ctx2.textBaseline = "top"; // <-- need to set it *after* resize to get it to work
ctx2.fillText("hi", 10, 10);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does seem to be the behavior specified. See the definition of ["set bitmap dimensions" in the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-set-bitmap-dimensions). That algorithm, which resets the state of the CanvasRenderingContext2D object, is invoked when the width or height properties of the HTMLCanvasElement itself change:

> When the user agent is to set bitmap dimensions to width and height, it must run these steps:
>
> 1. Reset the rendering context to its default state.
> 2. [...]

The "state" of the canvas context is also explicitly defined [in the 2D Context spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#the-canvas-state), and `textBaseline` is listed as one of the properties composing its state. It is [reiterated in the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#drawing-state) as well.

Comment: Ahh, so the whole context gets reset! Thanks. I should have tested other properties of ctx: http://jsbin.com/gifurimole/edit?html,output